# Basic question - Texmaker very slow and laggy when editing \chapter{}, \section, \label

Tags: texmaker

I am using a basic setup of texmaker to write my thesis. The editor freezes for a couple of seconds and is in general very laggy when I try to edit chapter names/section/labels (the xyz in \chapter{xyz}, \section{xyz}, \label{xyz}).

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It works well  for me but with a MWE, probably another OS, another LaTeX distro and another texmaker version, what could we tell you with those clues?  That I guessing that your thesis is a single huge file? If texmaker work fast with  simple small documents, consider split your thesis in subdocuments and use `\include{}` in the main file.